# Pull Data from Order form into Summary

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am currently updating our company's Excel order form and we now require it to work better digitally rather than people print it out and fill in manually.

On the first sheet I have the order form that the customer fills the quantities needed in to. As it needs to look nice rather than work well with formula's/macros its formatting isn't very standardised but each product is laid out in columns, left to right:

```
Code/Description     Unit Price    Quantity     Total
```

[image: Order Form Layout]

I need to pull this data across to a summary sheet but only if a quantity is entered against product.

On the summary sheet there is a much more organised table with, in columns, left to right:

```
Quantity    Code/Description    Unit Price    Sub-Total
```

[image: Summary Sheet Layout]

How should I be going about this? Formulae or Macros and if so point me the right direction and I can try and take it from there.

Comment: What should be in your summary table in this example?

Comment: Only products that have a quantity next to them. Then it should pull across the product desc/code from the same row along with the price and quantity.

Comment: So what happens with qty 2 when there is no description filled out?

Comment: Sorry my example is not complete, assume there is a description in each cell.

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to the cells from the first sheet in the second sheet quite readily - for example, in the second sheet, set the first quantity entry as:

```
= Sheet1!$A$2
```

and so on, with each cell in the 'standard' sheet referencing the appropriate cell on the first sheet.

You can even do this across workbooks:

```
= [workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2
```

And you can further do custom formatting to have cells on the 'standard' sheet left empty if the corresponding cell in the first sheet is empty, by creating a new cell format style as follows:

```
0; -0; ;@
```

and then setting the format of the cells to that style.

EDIT:

based on your note below, you could do conditional formatting on the 'standard' sheet, so that all cells in a row are blank if there's no corresponding quantity on the first sheet.

Because you can't specify conditional formatting formulas in reference to another sheet or workbook, do this in two steps:

1. format the quantity on the 'standard' sheet as above, by referencing other sheet
2. format other cells on 'standard' sheet according to the 'standard' quantity (specified in 1.) - to do this:

   a) set a new rule based on a formula for the cell:

   = $A$2 = 0

(or whatever cell on the standard that you want to reference for quantity)

b) set the conditional format of the cell (e.g. 'product description') that has the new rule to be:
    ; ; ; ;

(Note: I'm using an older version of Excel, and when I go from a zero value to a non-zero value, the conditional formatting is applied, but doesn't show up - if I save and re-open, everything looks fine, but I don't know if this is a version-specific issue. There's some discussion of this near the bottom of this thread: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/conditional-formatting-does-not-update/08fed959-df7a-4e43-a0ae-a2aa5f587edd?db=5&auth=1)

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding. I am aware of how to link cells but I only want them to show on the 2nd sheet on the condition that there has been a quantity entered.